# Hotspot for ssh control at boot

Tags: boot, dhcp, bash, hotspot

I bought my first Raspberry yesterday (RPi 3).

I have already installed an ssh server and I would like to run a script that create an hotspot on boot.

My intent is to boot the RPi 3, connect to the hotspot with my Android and manage it via SSH.

I already tried:

1. Putting the path of my script in `/etc/rc.local`
2. Create a service in `/etc/init.d`
3. `crontab -e` -> @reboot

but the script is launched before network interfaces or it doesn't work at all.

I'll post my script here:

```
#!/bin/bash

# install
# apt-get install airmon-ng hostapd isc-dhcp-server -y

killall dhcpd
killall hostapd
airmon-ng check kill

. conf.cfg

echo "Configuring hostapd..."

###########################################################

rm -r /etc/hostapd/*

(echo "interface=$interfaccia
driver=nl80211
ssid=$ssid
hw_mode=g
channel=$canale
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=$hidessid
wpa=$wpa
wpa_passphrase=$wpa_passphrase
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP") >> /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf

#hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf >/dev/null &

hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf >/dev/null &

echo "Hostapd started."

echo "Wait to start server dhcp..."
sleep $sleep_time

###########################################################

#mkdir /var/lib/dhcp
#touch /var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases

ifconfig $interfaccia  up
ifconfig $interfaccia  192.168.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0

touch /var/run/dhcpd.pid
chmod 777 /var/run/dhcpd.pid

rm /etc/dhcpd.conf

(echo "authoritative;
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
subnet 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
        option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
        option broadcast-address 192.168.0.255;
        option routers 192.168.0.1;
        option domain-name-servers 192.168.0.1; #DNS SERVER
        range 192.168.0.2 192.168.0.202;
}") >> /etc/dhcpd.conf

#dhcpd -q -cf /etc/dhcpd.conf $interfaccia  >/dev/null &

dhcpd -q -cf /etc/dhcpd.conf $interfaccia  >/dev/null &

echo "HOTSPOT ONLINE, SSID: $ssid"
```

and `conf.cfg` here:

```
#General
interfaccia=wlan0
internet=wlan1
sleep_time=1

#Network
ssid="TESTNET"
bssid=00:AA:11:BB:22:CC
canale=6
hidessid=0          #Hide SSID
wpa=0               #3=ON 0=OFF
wpa_passphrase="testtest"   #Min 8 char
```

This script works fine if launched from terminal after login in XServer.
But I want make it work before login without XServer and before the login. (Log-in should be via ssh, because no display will be connected to the RPi 3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake was to try the whole process in a virtual machine, today i tried directly on the raspberry and i solved it putting this line of code in the /etc/rc.local file:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

/script_path/./script.sh

exit 0
```

I hope this can help somebody else with the same problem.